# handling javascript alert 'forgot password' using selenium2

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, alert

There is a "forgot Password" link on login page. on clicking on this link, javascript pop comes up "do you want to retrieve your password". Script is failing in 4/10 attempts if i use below code with exception as "no alert is present"

```
Alert testAlrt = driver.switchTo().alert();
String sAltText = testAlrt.getText();
testAlrt.accept();
```

then i put the 10 secs explicit wait using

```
WebDriverWait wdWait= new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wdWait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
```

Still i get the same behaviour and sometimes i get following exception:

```
"org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for alert to be present"
```

Also, i observed that the "forgot password" link in firefox instance launched by Selenium is not functional. However, in my firefox instance, the link is functional.

Any idea? help is really appreciated.

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: *How* is the popup launched? I.e what *exact code* is used by the page to launch that popup?

Comment: this is what is there in page source file

<a href="javascript:handleForgotPassword();" onClick="javascript:return confirm('Do you want to retrieve your password?')">Forgot password?</a>